# How to Sort NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

I am having `NSMutableArray` containing objects like 
`[1,10,100,101,32A,32B,75,76,77,GAOTHAN]`, I want to sort this array in ascending order.
I am using below code but it is not working, As I don't have any key in my array. If anybody having solution please let me know.

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" 
                                                           ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
NSArray *reverseOrder = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Comment: Take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
-(void)sortArray
{
      NSMutableArray *unsortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"10",@"100",@"32A",@"32B",@"GAOTHAN", nil];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject)
                            {
        return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options:NSNumericSearch]; }];
    NSLog(@"Array is ::%@",sortedArray);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add compare method

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)otherObject {
    return [self compare:otherObject];
}
```

Call this method using the below code which return you sorted array.

```
NSMutableArray * arrayToFilter = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"10",@"100",@"101",@"32A",@"32B",@"75",@"76",@"77",@"GAOTHAN",nil];

NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayToFilter sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

you can write you own logic to compare two object of your array.